# How to use wget to continue my interrupted downloading

Tags: directory, wget

I use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to download all files in a directory of a site. But it was interrupted. How could I make it to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `wget -c url`, where `-c` stands for continue and `url` is the URL of the interrupted file.